# How to upload files using submit without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl, submit, form-submit

I am uploading files to the tomcat server using a submit button but my problem is that the page is reloading. If I use `return false` the file is not uploaded. I tried to use button its not uploading the files.

I am using `jstl` and javascript for my client side.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="uploadItem" name="frm" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload File</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label for="fileData" path="fileData">File</form:label><br />
                </td>
                <td><form:input path="fileData" id="csv" type="file" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><br /></td>
                <td><input id="subUpload" type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

For my javascript:

```
$("#subUpload").click(function(e) {
    var image = document.getElementById("csv").value;
    if(image!=''){
        var checkimg = image.toLowerCase();
            if (!checkimg.match(/(\.CSV|\.csv)$/)){
                alert("Please enter  Image  File Extensions .jpg,.png,.jpeg");
                document.getElementById("image").focus();
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I also used `e.preventDefault()` but still its reloading.

Please help.

Comment: Instead of `!checkimg.match(/(\.CSV|\.csv)$/)` you can just do `!/\.csv$/i.test(checking)`

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks for the sugeestion regarding the regex.

Answer (score 2):

this is possible if you use an iframe.

Comment: You mean Im gonna wrap the form inside an iframe?

Comment: http://www.devrecipes.com/2009/07/13/ajax-style-file-upload-without-page-refresh/

i just googled this up, example code is there -  i think the most file uploaders out there are using an iframe to handle this without page reload.

a very popular uploader is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: u have to build up the form in the iframe and send it with javascript, then listen on the onload event of the iframe and you know when the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

- Anything under and in the same block with `return [optional value here];` will be omitted so your `e.preventDefault()` line will never get executed.
- `return true` will tell the button to behave normal, so it will try to take its regular action
- `return false` and `e.preventDefault()` will do the same thing (stop the form from submitting the file), except, `return false` additionally blocks bubbling the click event up the document.

If you want to send the file seamlessly you might want to use an iframe or send the data using jQuery instead of letting the form to handle that data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use uploadify type component which can upload  a file before submission of a form

Answer (score -1):

create a form.. ex

```
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php">
<input type="file" name="piture"  value="" onChange="window.document.forms['form'].submit();"/> </form>
```

test.php

```
  if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)$/', $_FILES['picture']['name'])) {  
    $rand=rand(000000000,9999999);
    $fl_name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
    $expld = explode('.', $fl_name);
    $extnnew = $expld[1];
    $filename = $rand.'.'.$extnnew;  
    $source = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
    $path_to_image_directory = "uploads/"; 
    if(!is_dir($path_to_image_directory)){
mkdir($path_to_image_directory, 0777);
chmod($path_to_image_directory, 0777);} 

    $target = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;  
    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);  
    $sql ="insert into picture values('','".$filename."','Now()')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                        } 
header('Location:page.php');
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all.