# Form Submission without url refreshing

Tags: jquery, forms

My code is here

```
<form action="/custom/moustache/save_image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image_data" id="imageLoader"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
```

Please someone help me how can i submit my file without URL refreshing.

Comment: when you say without url refreshing, you mean no page refresh at all? You would need to use AJAX of some sort, jQuery Ajax would be a good option.

Comment: Please read [http://www.whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: sir please help me how can i submit my page using ajax because in form i have a file tag

Comment: If you don't care about the output of submission, just specify the id of a hidden iframe on your form. Easiest.

Comment: Follow this example http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files using submit without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487832/how-to-upload-files-using-submit-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***HTML 5:*** [Use Blueimp fileupload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

***HTML 4:*** Use iframe with it and submit

```
<iframe id="uploadTrg" name="uploadTrg" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

<form id="myForm" 
    action="http://example.com/file-upload-service" method="post"    
    enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="uploadTrg">

    File: <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn"/>

</form>
```

Then

```
$("iframe").load(function(){

alert("The file is uploaded");


$.post('http://example.com/file-upload- 
     service?do=getLastFile',null,function(attachment){

     $("#ajaxResultTest").append("<h4>" + attachment.name + ":" +
                                     attachment.id "</h4>");

 },'json');
});
```